# How can l replace data/data files?

Tags: android

I was working with my phone and unfortunately, l erased one of my data/data folders about storage and now my gallery is empty and my categories (in file manager)is empty too but l can rich my files and app and photos and etc with local/internal (in file manager).l don't remember the name of that file.

Could you tell me how can l have that file again without updating or changing my android??????

my android version is 4.4.2(and my phone model is Huawei Honor Holly(Hol_U19))

Comment: Your question is almost unintelligible. Please, edit it and clarify what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> l erased one of my data/data folders

Unrecoverable, sorry for your loss.